# How to get NSDecimalNumber from NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary, floating-point-precision, nsdecimalnumber

I want to set the value for `Key1`  as `10.00` itself rather than `10`

```
            NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                 [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"10.00"],
                                 [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"10.19"],nil]
                                 forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Key1",@"Key2",nil]];


            NSLog(@"Value For Key1 NSDecimalNumber %@",[dict valueForKey:@"Key1"]);
            NSLog(@"Value For Key1 float %f",[[dict valueForKey:@"Key1"] floatValue]);

            NSLog(@"Value For Key2 NSDecimalNumber %@",[dict valueForKey:@"Key2"]);
            NSLog(@"Value For Key2 float %f",[[dict valueForKey:@"Key2"] floatValue]);
```

This is the log that I get from the console

```
    2013-05-16 12:43:23.316 SampleTest[6569:19d03] Value For Key1 NSDecimalNumber 10
    2013-05-16 12:43:23.771 SampleTest[6569:19d03] Value For Key1 float 10.000000
    2013-05-16 12:43:24.263 SampleTest[6569:19d03] Value For Key2 NSDecimalNumber 10.19
    2013-05-16 12:43:25.195 SampleTest[6569:19d03] Value For Key2 float 10.190000
```

Can anyone help me out???

Thanks in advance..

Comment: OK so this is your problem. Why are you creating NSDecimalNumber, Keep it simple lady. use NSString.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya : I tried using NSString but the server side guys want it as number.The problem is very simple, I want that json formatted string with precision for decimal values even if the decimal part is zero.In my DB all decimal values are kept as NSDecimalNumber and integers as NSNumber

Comment: This looks like a server side problem to me. Sending JSON as `{ "Key1" = 10 }` or `{ "Key1" = 10.00 }` should make no difference.

Comment: @MartinR : Ya, it seems so.But I need to investigate what can be done from iOS side

Answer (score 1):

If you just need a formatted string with precision for decimal values. You can use

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",[[dict valueForKey:@"Key1"] floatValue]];
NSLog(@"str - %@",str);
```

str will always have the string with precision of 2 digits.

Hope this helps and is simple.

Comment: I want to as NSNumberDecimal, not as string

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to control the output format of your `NSDecimalNumber` object.
Cocoa provides the `NSNumberFormmatter` class for that purposes. It allows you to customize the string representation of your number without modifying the actual value.

`NSDecimalNumber` is a good choice if you have to deal with numbers that require high precision. E.g. when working with currencies.

I modified your sample to output a formatted version of the first value stored in the `dict`:

```
NSDictionary* dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                                          [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"10.00"],
                                                          [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"10.19"],nil]
                                                 forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Key1",@"Key2",nil]];
NSNumberFormatter* formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[formatter setAllowsFloats:YES];
[formatter setAlwaysShowsDecimalSeparator:YES];
[formatter setFormat:@"#,##0.00"];
NSString* formattedValue = [formatter stringFromNumber:[dict valueForKey:@"Key1"]];
NSLog(@"Value For Key1 %@",formattedValue);
```

Comment: I want to as NSNumberDecimal, not as string